# loadDataWithBaseURL not loading remote CSS

Tags: android, css, android-webview

I have an app that downloads the HTML data for a page and then loads it in a web view using loadDataWithBaseURL so that the data can be preloaded and always available when the user is offline. The problem is that even when the device is online, the CSS files that are in the HTML aren't loaded form the base url. Images work fine, but the formatting is all off. All of the other questions I've seen on here are with the opposite problem, they are trying to load local CSS files, or they are using loaddata instead of loadDataWithBaseUrl so searching here hasn't helped me thus far.

Here is my code to get the HTML data:

```
public static String getUrlContent(Context context, String url) {
    String result = null;
    try {
        HttpClient http_client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost http_post = new HttpPost(url); 
        HttpResponse response = http_client.execute(http_post); 

        result = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       
    return result;  
}
```

The code for loading the url in the web view is as simple as:

```
loadDataWithBaseURL(context.getString(R.string.base_url), data, "text/html","utf-8","");
```

With the base_url values from the configuration.xml file obviously being the base URL of the HTML data. I've double check that its value is correct, but still receive no proper formatting for my web view output.

My web view is setup like so:

```
WebSettings settings = getSettings();
settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
settings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
settings.setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
settings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
settings.setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8");
settings.setUseWideViewPort(false);
settings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
    settings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
```

I'm also using a custom web view client and web chrome client, but disabling those doesn't fix the issue, so I don't think the code for them is relevant. Most of the CSS is linked in the html with link tags if that helps any.

Comment: try making the first and last parameter as `null` in `loadDataWithBaseURL`..

Comment: webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, data, "text/html","UTF-8",null);

Comment: That didn't work. It has to have some way to know what URL to use to resolve the CSS links since the CSS files aren't downloaded with the HTML. Is there some other way of providing that data that I don't know about?

Comment: which version of Android are you seeing this on?

Comment: also, could you paste what is R.string.base_url and what do the CSS <link /> tags look like?